# Recovering mechanical energy from natural gas water boiler

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

Is there any heat energy lost to the mechanical force of pushing a piston in a combustion engine?

In other words, would a natural gas burning as a flame produce more heat than the same amount of natural gas that was burned when driving a combustion engine?

The context of this question is around fuel efficiency of natural gas water boilers.

My current understanding is that a naked natural gas flame is burning inside the unit, and heats water that is contained within a series of pipes, which in turn is cooled in a heat exchanger, and that same heat exchanger heats the incoming cool water.

I'm wondering, would if it make any sense at all to burn that natural gas inside a combustion engine and use the heat of the combustion engine used to heat the water to the same extent as a naked flame.

More generally my goal is to solve the question, can we heat water the same extent by burning the same amount of natural gas **and** get free mechanical energy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out combined heat and power systems... generates electricity and makes use of the waste heat to heat water - but is only really efficient when there is sufficient hot water demand ie heating load.

Comment: this looks to be exactly the kind of appliance that I was dreaming of! Thanks! I'd like to  upvote your response but I have too few reputation points at the moment

Comment: You can use the check mark to accept the answer if you wish...

Comment: Good answer Solar Mike!